# Arcpy CopyRows writes only a fraction of MakeQueryLayer results

Tags: arcpy, query-layer

I have a query running against an Oracle non-spatial database that returns thousands of records, but when I run `CopyRows` against that query only 24 rows are carried over! What the heck is going on? I've tried with both ArcMap Python 2.7 and Pro Python 3.6.

```
query = '''SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ...'''
view = arcpy.management.MakeQueryLayer(
    input_database=input_database, 
    out_layer_name=bph_layer, 
    query=query, 
    oid_fields="", 
    shape_type="", 
    srid="", 
    spatial_reference="")
arcpy.management.CopyRows(view, bph_table)

print('Records from DB ({}): {}'.format(bph_layer, arcpy.management.GetCount(bph_layer)))
print('Records in View result ({}): {}'.format(view, arcpy.management.GetCount(view)))
print('Records out to {}: {}'.format(bph_table, arcpy.management.GetCount(bph_table)))
```

Emits:

```
Records from DB (BPH_plots_for_distribution_layer): 10139
Records in View result (BPH_plots_for_distribution_layer): 10139
Records out to BPH_plots_for_distribution: 24
```

Answer (score 1):

This took several hours to get to the bottom of this one. Like so many issues the cure is dead simple, but only if you know what the problem is. In this case: **the problem is not specifying an Object ID field** (which contains unique numeric values).

Q: So why were 24 records returned and not 3600 or ...?

A: Without an explicit ObjectID CopyRows is automatically selecting some field to use, and in this instance that column only has 24 unique values.

One attempted fix is too explicitly declare the real ID field:

```
view = arcpy.management.MakeQueryLayer(
    ...
    oid_fields="BPH_PLOT_ID", 
    ...)
```

This workded, but has the highly undesirable side effect of converting the ID field's name into OBJECTID *and overwriting the original values*. This is a known but not highly publicized byproduct of CopyRows tool (and probably others).

Another often suggested remedy is to `CAST ROWNUM as OBJECTID`. This is bad juju!  When you use ROWNUM, it returns a value which may not describe a row. Imagine a selection set of the first three rows returned by a spatial query, {1,2,3}. If the query extent is changed, the selected rows will change, and so will your object id's.

To workaround that, **include the unique ID field in the query twice, once as OBJECTID and again as RealID**.

In this example BPH_PLOT_ID is my RealID:

```
query = '''SELECT
    CAST (BPH_PLOT_ID as number(38)) as OBJECTID,
    BPH_PLOT_ID, ...    
    FROM ... WHERE ...'''

view = arcpy.management.MakeQueryLayer(
    ...
    oid_fields="OBJECTID", 
    ...)
```

Note: Leave "objectid" in the first position, since sometimes the first NOT NULL integer gets promoted.

And finally remember in any future re-use of this derived data to only use realid and ignore objectid.

Comment: Casting ROWNUM is bad juju if you use it in mapping. Be *careful* that this solution doesn't cause a worse problem.

Comment: @vince can you elaborate or point to where that's covered?

Comment: ...or better yet, what's the best practice method to use instead

Comment: The requirement is that the value be unique, but that the value must identify a specific row.  When you use ROWNUM, it returns a value which may not describe a row. Imagine a selection set of the first three rows returned by a spatial query, {1,2,3}.  If the query extent is changed, the selected rows will change.  The only way to avoid this is to use a value which exists in the row.

Comment: thank you @Vince. That helps a me great deal in the general sense. It's something I've not understood properly before. In this specific instance though I _was_ passing a unique record identifier but CopyRows threw away that info and rewrote it with something else.

Comment: Yes, that's what CopyRows does.  Better to include `SELECT objectid,objectid as orig_id ...` so the overridden value is sacrificed, but you still have a copy.  Better to leave the column "objectid" in the first position, since sometimes the first NOT NULL integer gets promoted.

Comment: Thank you @Vince. Rewritten to remove the bad examples and folded in your excellent comments